# Query cannot pickup anything with an ID > 0, just errors [heroku]

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I am attempting to setup a SQL database for a game on ROBLOX, and creating queries using express. A specific query uses a query to get different id's, and it should return everything from the specific id in the sql table, which works perfectly fine, apart from when the ID is higher than 0.
Here's the code in node, not sure what else needs to be shown;

```
app.get('/client/getgroupinfo.php', function(req, res){
    var Lawa = req.query.gid;
    connection.connect();
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM `guilds` WHERE `id` = ' + Lawa, function(err, rows,fields){
        connection.end();
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(rows);
    });
});
```

It should be worth mentioning that the ID's that exist are:
0, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10

Comment: What happens when you do the same query in the MySQL command line tool (or your favorite DB tool)?

Comment: FWIW, the examples on [the `mysql` `npm` page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) show calling `connection.end()` after `connection.query()`, not from within its callback. (And it says it waits for all active queries to complete before sending the quit command to MySQL.) Given that example, why are you doing `connection.end()` *within* the callback?

Comment: It returns both rows separately

Comment: Also note that `if (err) throw err;` is incorrect. That throws an error to the code calling the query callback. You need to call your error reporting/handling code instead.

Comment: i see, i'll fix that now i guess

Comment: Other than the `connection.end` thing and the fact that the code uses string concatenation from user input to build an SQL query (which is a **very** bad idea, let me introduce you to [my friend Bobby](https://bobby-tables.com/)), assuming `req.query.gid` matches an `id` on one or more rows in the `guilds` table, that query should return rows.